# Equivalence of Frobenius norm and trace norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, trace, nuclear-norm

According to [[1]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.4320&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [[2]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.916&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and other related publications, the following holds for any matrix $X$:

$$\| X\|_\Sigma=\min_{X=UV'}\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}=\min_{X=UV'}\frac{1}{2}(\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}^{2}+\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}^2)$$

where $\|\cdot\|_\Sigma$ is the trace (nuclear/Ky-Fan) norm and $\|\cdot\|_\mathrm{Fro}$ is the Frobenius norm.

Can anyone show why this equality is true?

In the publications, it is filed under "Preliminaries" and one of the few Lemmas without proof. I find this relationship very fundamental and interesting, but could not find it anywhere else, let alone proof.

Thank you for any help!

**What I already have:**

If I understand the 'hint' in ref. 1 (above) correctly, $\min_{X=UV'}\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}$ is minimized by $U=\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda}$ and $V=\hat{V}\sqrt{\Lambda}$, where $X=\hat{U}\Lambda \hat{V'}$ is the singlular value decomposition of $X$ (Page 75, Lemma 8 in ref. 1 (above)).

Comment: By the AM-GM inequality, it suffices to show that
$$
\min_{X=UV'}\|U\|_{Fro}\|V\|_{Fro} \geq \min_{X=UV'}\frac{1}{2}(\|U\|_{Fro}^{2}+\|V\|_{Fro}^2)
$$
Also, note that $\|A\|_{Fro}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n [\sigma_i(A)]^2$

Comment: @new2you : You correctly wrote \|U\| rather than ||U||, which puts you ahead of many around here. But when you write "a min b" instead of "a\min b", then you see $a min b$ instead of $a\min b$, so min gets italicized and it doesn't have proper spacing between min and what comes before and after it, and moreover, in a "displayed", as opposed to "inline" setting, using \min affects the format, so that you see $\displaystyle a\min_b c$ instead of $a min_b c$, with the subscript directly under "$\min$". I also used \mathrm{Fro} where you had {Fro} and $\|\cdot\|$ where you had $\|.\|$.${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks, will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: AM-GM inequality certainly fits, thanks! Your substitution of $\|A\|^2_\mathrm{Fro}$ simplifies the inequality to a point where the equality of both sides can only happen if $\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}=\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}$ (the 'equality' case of the AM-GM inequality). As far as I understand $U$ and $V$ can have different singular values, however, so also their squared sums can be different and $\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}=\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}$ cannot hold. I am still lost, sorry.

Comment: You're allowed to be lost :) I'll try to find a more helpful hint if I find the time and if I myself find the right direction here.  Thoughts: If you can show that $\|U\| \|V\|$ is minimized with the particular $U,V,$ it suffices to find a $U,V$ for which $(\|U\|^2+ \|V\|^2)/2$ is less than or equal to that.

Answer (score 2):

2nd equality: the $\le$ is just AM-GM inequality.  To get $=$, replace $U$ by $\lambda U$ and $V$ by $\lambda^{-1}V$ so that the norms of $U$ and $V$ become the same.

1st equality: the hint tells you how to get $\ge$.  So suppose that $X = UV$.  Let the singular decomposition of $X = Q \Lambda P^*$, where $Q$ and $P$ are unitary, and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with non-negative entries.  Then $\Lambda = Q^* U V P$, and so $$\|X\|_\Sigma = \text{trace}(\Lambda) \le \|Q^* U\|_F \|V P\|_F = \|U\|_F \|V\|_F .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was writing a proof while you posted this. Not sure though: either I have a mistake or the inequality can become an equality.

Comment: This is a very nice proof!

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda}$ and $V=\hat{V}\sqrt{\Lambda}$, where $X=\hat{U}\Lambda \hat{V'}$ is the singlular value decomposition of $X$.

**1. Equation:** $\| X\|_\Sigma=\min_{X=UV'}\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}$

$\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}((\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda})(\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda})^\intercal)\mathrm{trace}((\hat{V}\sqrt{\Lambda})(\hat{V}\sqrt{\Lambda})^\intercal)}=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda}\sqrt{\Lambda}^\intercal\hat{U}^\intercal)\mathrm{trace}(\hat{V}\sqrt{\Lambda}\sqrt{\Lambda}^\intercal\hat{V}^\intercal)}=$

Using the facts that (i) $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix (ii) the trace of multiplied matrices does not change under cyclic rotations (iii) $\hat{U}$ and $\hat{V}$ are unitary:

$=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(\hat{U}\Lambda\hat{U}^\intercal)\mathrm{trace}(\hat{V}\Lambda\hat{V}^\intercal)}=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(\hat{U}^\intercal\hat{U}\Lambda)\mathrm{trace}(\hat{V}^\intercal\hat{V}\Lambda)}=\sqrt{\mathrm{trace}(\Lambda)\mathrm{trace}(\Lambda)}=\mathrm{trace}(\Lambda)=\| X\|_\Sigma$

**2. Equation:** $\min_{X=UV'}\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}=\min_{X=UV'}\frac{1}{2}(\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}^{2}+\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}^2)$

The AM GM inequality states that the geometric mean and the arithmetic mean are equal if the numbers being averaged are all the same. It is therefore enough to show that $\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}^{2}=\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}^2$.

As in **1.**:

$\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}^{2}=\|\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda}\|_\mathrm{Fro}^2=\mathrm{trace}((\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda})(\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda})^\intercal)=\mathrm{trace}(\Lambda)=\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}^{2}$

The only thing missing: why does $U=\hat{U}\sqrt{\Lambda}$ and $V=\hat{V}\sqrt{\Lambda}$ minimize $\min_{X=UV'}\|U\|_\mathrm{Fro}\|V\|_\mathrm{Fro}$?